# BPEL, initialize variable and repeating onAlarm eventHandler

Tags: initialization, bpel

I have a little problem I can't solve so far. In BPEL I want to create an onAlarm eventHandler which fires immediatly (i.e. the "for" element is set to 'PT0S') and repeats every 2 seconds. This eventHandler shall contain a counter which increments every time the alarm fires.

The question is: How to initialize the counter? If the variable will be initialized within the onAlarm scope the value would not increment anymore. In the "normal" control flow the value also cannot be initialized, because it is not defined if the process or the onAlarm scope runs first. So I would get every now and then an uninitializedVariable exception.

My solution would be to not initialize the variable neither in the process scope nor in the onAlarm scope, but create a faultHandler wherein the variable will be initialized and afterwards the onAlarm flow will be executed. Problem is every uninitializedVariable execution will be caught now by this faultHandler and there may be another too.

So is there another possibility to deal with this problem or can I somehow find out which variable wasn't initialized properly so the faultHandler can get two control flows?

The solution should work on every BPEL engine.

Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a variable with a default value on its definition using a `from-spec` just like in an assignment. See [section 8.4.1 of the spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/OS/wsbpel-v2.0-OS.html#_Toc164738495) for the details.

A default initialization can look like this:

```
<variables>
    <variable name="Default" type="xsd:int" >
        <from>5</from>
    </variable>
</variables>
```

This should work as `eventHandlers` are installed after the start activity of a process has completed. By then, the variables defined in the root scope have already been initialized. To quote the [spec, section 12.1](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/OS/wsbpel-v2.0-OS.html#_Toc164738523):

> Scope initialization consists of instantiating and initializing the
>   scope's variables and partner links; ... If a scope contains an
>   initial start activity then the start activity MUST complete before
>   the event handlers are installed.

So much for spec. I think nobody can tell whether this "works on every BPEL engine". As far as I know, it works on bpel-g, Orchestra and EasyBPEL, but not on Apache ODE or OpenESB.

Comment: Hi joergl,

thanks for your answer. Unfortunately i can't test it, because I'm using Apache ODE. Well I guess your approach can work also, so I'll mark it as solved.

I was a bit dumb as I created this thread. My workaround: I create an extra scope just for the assign activity and surround it by a faulthandler. This way I only catch the error of this one and only activity.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I wouldn't call the question dumb, BPEL is not really easy to understand ;) This solution may be more "clean" than the workaround you describe, but workarounds are something inevitable when working with today's engines. So your solution is also fine.